# Dojo 1.7 form setFormValues during startup

Tags: html, dojo

Being new to Dojo I'm trying to initialize a Dijit form with values, e.g. read from storage, XHR etc.

However, invoking `form.setFormValues()` causes an error `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand this.formWidgets` thrown by http://yandex.st/dojo/1.7.3/dojox//form/manager/_Mixin.js

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is this a Dojo issue? (The complete sample is also found here: http://pastebin.com/7LUHr3iA)

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
`
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojoConfig = {async: true,parseOnLoad: true};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/dojo/1.7.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dijit/form/TextBox","dijit/form/Button","dojox/form/Manager",
                "dojo/parser","dojo/dom","dijit/registry"], function () {});
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">

    <form id="myForm" method="post" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Manager">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="nameField" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"/><br/>

        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input id="surname" name="surnameField" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"/><br/>

        <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Submit</button>

        <script type="dojo/method" event="startup">
            var form = dijit.byId("myForm");

            form.setFormValues({
                nameField: "Hello",
                surnameField: "World"
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo 1.7 is asynchronous. Code should take the form:

```
require(["dependency"], function(dep) {
  // use dependency
});
```

There is no reason to believe `dojox/form/Manager` would be loaded when you try to reference it further down the page.

The registry is the correct way to reference the widget, not 1.6 style code of the form `dijit.byId`. See [livedocs](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/byId).

*See also the [`dojo/domReady!`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/domReady.html) plugin.*

Comment: thx for your advice -- it was definitely a timing/dependency issue. And actually no need to utilize startup. A fixed outline has been posted: http://pastebin.com/r07emy1e